# shallow-copy a segment of a value type array

Tags: c#, arrays, shallow-copy

I'm trying to shallow-copy a double[] into segments, and pass those segments to new threads, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threadsArray.Length; i++)
{
    sub[i] = new double[4];

    //Doesn't shallow copy since double is a value type
    Array.Copy(full, i * 4, sub[i], 0, 4);
    double[] tempSub = sub[i];

    threadsArray[i] = new Thread(() => DoStuff(tempSub));
    threadsArray[i].Start();               
}
```

What would be the best way to have the created segments reference the original array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`ArraySegment<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) structure:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threadsArray.Length; i++)
{
    sub[i] = new ArraySegment<double>(full, i * 4, 4);

    ArraySegment<double> tempSub = sub[i];

    threadsArray[i] = new Thread(() => DoStuff(tempSub));
    threadsArray[i].Start(); 
}
```

(note that you will need to change the signature of `DoStuff` to accept an `ArraySegment<double>` (or at least an `IList<double>` instead of an array)

`ArraySegment<T>` doesn't copy the data; it just represents an segment of the array, by keeping a reference to the original array, an offset and a count. Since .NET 4.5 it implements `IList<T>`, which means you can use it without worrying about manipulating the offset and count.

In pre-.NET 4.5, you can create an extension method to allow easy enumeration of the `ArraySegment<T>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this ArraySegment<T> segment)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < segment.Count; i++)
    {
        yield return segment.Array[segment.Offset + i];
    }
}

...

ArraySegment<double> segment = ...
foreach (double d in segment.AsEnumerable())
{
    ...
}
```

If you need to access the items by index, you will need to create a wrapper that implements `IList<T>`. Here's a simple implementation: http://pastebin.com/cRcpBemQ

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I'm on .NET 4.0, so if I use it do I still have to keep track of the offset by passing it?